# django admin ordering not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

in this as you can saw we change order 1, and order 0

[image]

while running it still the same
you can saw

> using the shell
>   title at top and Whats the deal with strings?

while this has to be reverse according to the order`

Courses/model.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Course(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Step(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['order', ]
```

[image]

Comment: Is the `class Meta` inside the `class Step` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an indentation error. The Meta class for Step, which contains the ordering directive, is not actually inside the Step class. It needs to be indented one level.